# Table and scrollbar does not refesh

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

I am using bootstrap and have a table inside a  tag that I want to be able scroll horizontal as well as vertical. The table header is fixed and only the body scrolls. The script I have works fine when it is inside plain html without  but goes display  the data from the overflown columns and does not refresh properly. Any idea how it can be fixed? Attached is the screen shot.

```
<script>
$('table').on('scroll', function() {
$("#" + this.id + " > *").width($(this).width() + $(this).scrollLeft());
});
</script>


            <style>
            html {
                font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 10pt;
            line-height: 25px;
            }

            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 30000px;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            display: block;
            }

            thead {
                background-color: #EFEFEF;
            }

            thead,
            tbody {
                display: block;
            }

            tbody {
                overflow-y: hidden;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            height: 140px;
            }

            td,
            th {
                min-width: 100px;
            height: 25px;
            border: dashed 1px lightblue;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            max-width: 100px;
            }
            </style> 


<div ng-app="CCARApp" ng-controller="TaskController" data-ng-init="fetchTasks()" id="tabcontainer"  class="tab-content container" style="height:100%;width:100%;  display: flex;flex-direction: column;border-style: solid; border-color:  blue;" onscroll="myFunction(this)">

            <div id="14A Tasks" class="tab-pane fade in active col-sm-6 col-md-6 table-responsive" style="height:100%;width:100%; border-style: solid; border-color:  coral;" style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:auto;">

            <div class="spinner" ng-show="showLoader">
                <img src="./images/spinner.gif" align="middle" > 
            </div>


            <input class="form-control" id="delayedInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.."/>
                        <br>

                    <table id="tab" class="table" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                                <th>Process</th>  
                                                <th>Task Id</th>  
                                                <th>Task Mode</th> 
                                                <th>Group</th>  
                                                <th>Task Name</th> 
                                                <th>Duration</th> 
                                                <th>Start Date</th> 
                                                <th>Finish Date</th>
                                                <th>Predecessors</th>
                                                <th>Owner 1</th>
                                                <th>Owner 2</th>
                                                <th>Escalation</th>
                                                <th>Last Updated By</th>
                                                <th>Last Updated Date</th>
                                                <th>Status</th>
                                                <th>Comments</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                           <tbody style="height: 500px !important; overflow-y:scroll; ">
                                            <tr  >
                                                <td >test1</td>  
                                                <td >test2</td>  
                                                <td >test3</td>  
                                                <td >test4</td>  
                                                <td >test5</td>  
                                                <td >test6</td>  
                                                <td >test7</td>  
                                                <td >test8</td>  
                                                <td >test9</td>  
                                                <td >test10</td>  


                                                <td >test11</td>  
                                                <td >test12</td>  
                                                <td >test13</td>  
                                                <td >test14</td> 
                                                <td >test15</td> 
                                                 <td >test16</td> 

                                                </tr>  
                                                 <tr  >
                                                <td >test1</td>  
                                                <td >test2</td>  
                                                <td >test3</td>  
                                                <td >test4</td>  
                                                <td >test5</td>  
                                                <td >test6</td>  
                                                <td >test7</td>  
                                                <td >test8</td>  
                                                <td >test9</td>  
                                                <td >test10</td>  


                                                <td >test11</td>  
                                                <td >test12</td>  
                                                <td >test13</td>  
                                                <td >test14</td> 
                                                <td >test15</td> 
                                                 <td >test16</td> 

                                                </tr>  
                                                 <tr  >
                                                <td >test1</td>  
                                                <td >test2</td>  
                                                <td >test3</td>  
                                                <td >test4</td>  
                                                <td >test5</td>  
                                                <td >test6</td>  
                                                <td >test7</td>  
                                                <td >test8</td>  
                                                <td >test9</td>  
                                                <td >test10</td>  


                                                <td >test11</td>  
                                                <td >test12</td>  
                                                <td >test13</td>  
                                                <td >test14</td> 
                                                <td >test15</td> 
                                                 <td >test16</td> 

                                                </tr>  
                                                 <tr  >
                                                <td >test1</td>  
                                                <td >test2</td>  
                                                <td >test3</td>  
                                                <td >test4</td>  
                                                <td >test5</td>  
                                                <td >test6</td>  
                                                <td >test7</td>  
                                                <td >test8</td>  
                                                <td >test9</td>  
                                                <td >test10</td>  


                                                <td >test11</td>  
                                                <td >test12</td>  
                                                <td >test13</td>  
                                                <td >test14</td> 
                                                <td >test15</td> 
                                                 <td >test16</td> 

                                                </tr>  
                                                 <tr  >
                                                <td >test1</td>  
                                                <td >test2</td>  
                                                <td >test3</td>  
                                                <td >test4</td>  
                                                <td >test5</td>  
                                                <td >test6</td>  
                                                <td >test7</td>  
                                                <td >test8</td>  
                                                <td >test9</td>  
                                                <td >test10</td>  


                                                <td >test11</td>  
                                                <td >test12</td>  
                                                <td >test13</td>  
                                                <td >test14</td> 
                                                <td >test15</td> 
                                                 <td >test16</td> 

                                                </tr>  
                                                 <tr  >
                                                <td >test1</td>  
                                                <td >test2</td>  
                                                <td >test3</td>  
                                                <td >test4</td>  
                                                <td >test5</td>  
                                                <td >test6</td>  
                                                <td >test7</td>  
                                                <td >test8</td>  
                                                <td >test9</td>  
                                                <td >test10</td>  


                                                <td >test11</td>  
                                                <td >test12</td>  
                                                <td >test13</td>  
                                                <td >test14</td> 
                                                <td >test15</td> 
                                                 <td >test16</td> 

                                                </tr>  
                                                 <tr  >
                                                <td >test1</td>  
                                                <td >test2</td>  
                                                <td >test3</td>  
                                                <td >test4</td>  
                                                <td >test5</td>  
                                                <td >test6</td>  
                                                <td >test7</td>  
                                                <td >test8</td>  
                                                <td >test9</td>  
                                                <td >test10</td>  


                                                <td >test11</td>  
                                                <td >test12</td>  
                                                <td >test13</td>  
                                                <td >test14</td> 
                                                <td >test15</td> 
                                                 <td >test16</td> 

                                                </tr>  
                                                 <tr  >
                                                <td >test1</td>  
                                                <td >test2</td>  
                                                <td >test3</td>  
                                                <td >test4</td>  
                                                <td >test5</td>  
                                                <td >test6</td>  
                                                <td >test7</td>  
                                                <td >test8</td>  
                                                <td >test9</td>  
                                                <td >test10</td>  


                                                <td >test11</td>  
                                                <td >test12</td>  
                                                <td >test13</td>  
                                                <td >test14</td> 
                                                <td >test15</td> 
                                                 <td >test16</td> 

                                                </tr>  
                                                 <tr  >
                                                <td >test1</td>  
                                                <td >test2</td>  
                                                <td >test3</td>  
                                                <td >test4</td>  
                                                <td >test5</td>  
                                                <td >test6</td>  
                                                <td >test7</td>  
                                                <td >test8</td>  
                                                <td >test9</td>  
                                                <td >test10</td>  


                                                <td >test11</td>  
                                                <td >test12</td>  
                                                <td >test13</td>  
                                                <td >test14</td> 
                                                <td >test15</td> 
                                                 <td >test16</td> 

                                                </tr>  
                                                 <tr  >
                                                <td >test1</td>  
                                                <td >test2</td>  
                                                <td >test3</td>  
                                                <td >test4</td>  
                                                <td >test5</td>  
                                                <td >test6</td>  
                                                <td >test7</td>  
                                                <td >test8</td>  
                                                <td >test9</td>  
                                                <td >test10</td>  


                                                <td >test11</td>  
                                                <td >test12</td>  
                                                <td >test13</td>  
                                                <td >test14</td> 
                                                <td >test15</td> 
                                                 <td >test16</td> 

                                                </tr>  

                         </tbody>
                    </table>

            </div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by removing display:block on table tag